# Excel 2007 ComboBox without VBA

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to generate a combo box on a worksheet without using VBA.  I am very familiar with the process through VBA, but I would like this workbook to be maintained by users with no VBA experience.  I know there is a way to generate and fill a combo box without VBA but it has been eon's since I have used it.  Any refresher guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the ComboBox from insert menu in the developer tab?

Comment: Yes I have used both the Form and ActieX combobox.  I am lookingto change the cell into a combo box.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of Data Validation. This question is better suited to SuperUser.

Comment: No, no your answer is correct. I have not placed a simple data validation on a cell in a Looong time. Please post this as the answer so I can give you credit!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of Data Validation.

Comment: Cobwebs on a Desert Spider :). I like it.